# How to setup PayPal Express Recurring Payment using Reference Transaction?

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, paypal

I am trying to setup PayPal Express Recurring Payment using Reference Transaction. Can anybody help me to understand the flow of transactions. How to setup Reference Transaction? And after that how I handle Recurring Transaction using Reference Id?

Note: I am writing the code using Asp .Net MVC.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you @grochmal for your reply. I have solved this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup a Billing Agreement before the reference transaction could take place.

Basically, Billing Agreement is set using the Express Checkout. Two core steps of Reference Transactions are ;

1. Setup a payment authorization, and then create a billing agreement.
2. Setup a billing agreement, and then initiate a payment after the billing agreement is established.

Link :

Reference Transaction : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

Reference Transactions with Express Checkout : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/

Comment: In this document nowhere explain how to handle Recurring Payment using Reference Transaction.

Comment: Suppose, I have created Billing Agreement. Then how I will handle the billing cycle(Period, Frequency etc) as recursive in Reference Transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this problem.

- First need to setup Reference transaction and generate BillingId (Save BillingId for future transactions).

We have now BillingId, But the big question here. How to handle Recurring cycle's.

- For solving this issue we need to write our own script and maintain scheduling (Recurring Cycle). Use BillingId to deduct payment from buyer account.